# Artifactory Package copy from One Folder to another using Jenkins Job

Tags: shell, jenkins, copy-paste, artifactory

I need to copy the packages within Artifactory. For example from `dev-all` repository to `Qa-all` repository using my existing Jenkins job, where I will select the package at run time.
Please help me on how to write a script for this using shell and carry out task using Jenkins.

Comment: Within Artifactory*

Comment: what do you call "a package"? A Java package? Number of classes from within archive?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean an artifact when you say package...
Anyway, it's very easy to do such moving/copying with the JFrog CLI. It has all options to manipulate artifacts and metadata in Artifactory.

See [JFrog CLI](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/JFrog+CLI) here.
It's perfect for automation and Jenkins like tools.

There are many examples, and moving an artifact is easy ([moving files](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/JFrog+CLI#JFrogCLI-MovingFiles)).

I hope this helps.